# Node.js/Koa2 server - execute a job minutes after request

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa, koa2

I have a Koa2/Node.js app (using `async/await`) and I want to execute a job *X* minutes after request, where *X* is a random number of minutes ranging from 20 - 100 (I want to use it to send automatic welcome emails to users who sign up and make it appear like it was sent personally by me).

So can I just use `setTimeout` to do this, is it reasonable to set a timer for 200 minutes? Of course, if my app crashes, the email wouldn't be sent, but I will track all signups in database, so in a rare case of crash I will send the email myself.

Comment: Why don't you use SendGrid and create templates so the email process gets automated and the emails are sent instantly.  Much better user experience then waiting for 100 minutes to use the new site you just signed up for.

Comment: Actually I do use SendGrid and the email process is automated, I just want to automate the delay. And make it appear like it was sent by human, not bot.

Comment: If you can, a chron job would be better than setTimeout.

Comment: You should delegate the sending of the email and work outside of the request. Set a flag in database and use a cron job ? Or with something more fancy (redis pub/sub, rabbitMQ queue and process message with a script ?)

Comment: @MaciejKrawczyk: Could you please share how you eventually solved your problem?

Answer (score 3):

Command queue such as **rabbitMQ** or wraps around **Redis** (with pub/sub or `SETEX`) seems like an overhead for such simple task.

Timeouts for relatively long periods with potentially N requests do feel a bit uncomfortable, but Node.js `setTimout()` is actually a wrapper around `uv_timer` function in `libuv` which is designed to handle a huge amount of timers over the underlying OS notification mechanism.

Still, to keep things as simple as possible I would use a good old cron job with some wrapper library which hides exact implementation. With something like [`node-schedule`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) it could be done in just few lines of code.

```
const schedule = require('node-schedule');

const getRandomMsAmount = (from, to) => {
  const minutes = Math.floor(Math.random() * to) + from;
  return minutes * 60 * 1000;
};

const getDateAfterMs = (ms) => {
  const nowTimestamp = Number(new Date());
  return new Date(nowTimestamp + ms);
};

const dueDate = getDateAfterMs(getRandomMsAmount(20, 100));
const emailJob = schedule.scheduleJob(dueDate, () => {
  // logging, updating database, etc.
});
```

If something goes wrong during processing, referenced job can be cancelled:

```
emailJob.cancel();
```

I hope your email contains random content as well, because even single user can get multiple messages in case of different signup attempts - so this delay could become just an annoying experience.